# How to get a custom type post data when it has a connection with another custom type post?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I have two custom post types: Country and City.

**Country**

There is just a text field to fill with its name.

[image]

**City**

I have a text field for city's name and also a select with all the countries that was added in the other custom post type.

[image]

My question is, how to get for each city, its own country?

To retrieve the cities I'm using:

```
$args = array (
  'post_type' => 'cities'
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

In this result of cities, I don't have any information related to the country that I select in the admin area.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in a country looking for cities

```
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'cities',
    'meta_key' => 'country',
    'meta_value' => get_the_ID()
);
```

This assumes that the **"Country > Name* > [drop down]"** you screenshot saves that the selected value using `post_meta` and is saving the country's post ID. (If it does not please adjust or specify).

### UPDATE

To list cities, and retrieve their country_name, assuming the dropdown is just storing the post_title of the country, you could do:

```
$cities = get_posts(array (
    'post_type' => 'cities',
    'numberposts' => '-1',
));
foreach ($cities as $city) {
    $country_name = get_post_meta($city->ID,'country_name',true);
    // to get the full country, if country_name is just the post title (and not ID) you could do
    # $country = get_page_by_title( $country_name, 'object', 'country' );
    echo "<pre>City: {$city->post_title} is in country: {$country_name}</pre>":
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment David. This example that you wrote. I'm trying to get the city list, and for each city, get the country that I select in the admin area. 

The country is a custom type post as well, and the field name is country_name. This meta_key is related to the field name??

Comment: I'm unsure if your setup has the `country_name` saved as a meta value, and wether it saves as a string (the country name) or an ID - but that's normally how it's setup - can you please provide more info about how you've setup `country_name` within a city post type. Regardless, I've updated my post to list all cities with their respective country.

Comment: David, it worked. With your updated code, I could get the country ID.
country_name is the field name for my post_object. I should change just for country, will make more sense. Thanks very much!!! Now I will dig deeper to understand the query because I will need to create more complex queries. Thanks!